# Creating first degree navigation properties to handle complex relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design, entity-framework-6

We design an asset management system to track the tangible assets circulating in an institution. We use `ASP.NET MVC` architecture with `EF6` as our ORM.

**Entities**:

1. `Asset` is an equipment owned by the institution and may be assigned to its employees.
2. `Person` is an employee who are responsible for their given assets.
3. `Location` is a unit within the institution used to track the assets.
4. `MovementDoc` is a document including details about the mass movement of assets (like a reassignment/relocation operation fit for our example)
5. `AssetMovement` is any single movement process detail of an asset. Works like a junction entity between `Asset` and `MovementDoc`, but also has its own properties so it's not disposible.

**Relations**:

Every `Asset` encounters numerous movement processes in its lifetime.

```
public class Asset {
    public ICollection<AssetMovement> Movements { get; set; }
}
```

`AssetMovement` is the bridge entity necesarry to keep record

```
public class AssetMovement
{
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }
    public long? AssetId { get; set; }

    public MovementDoc Document { get; set; }
    public long? DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

`MovementDoc` may include many `AssetMovement` each related to a different `Asset`. It could point both to a `Person` or `Location`.

```
public class MovementDoc
{
    public Location TargetLocation { get; set; }
    public long? TargetLocationId { get; set; }

    public Person PersonReceived { get; set; }
    public long? PersonReceivedId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetMovement> Movements { get; set; }
}
```

This web of relations seems fit for our application. But in practice, it has some drawbacks.

**The issue**:

Our users want to list their assets listed in a datatable together with it's assigned people and location information. Our first approach is to create a computed property on `Asset`:

```
[NotMapped, Computed]
    public MovementDoc LastMovementDoc
    {
        get
        {
            if (Movements.Count == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return Movements.Select(x => x.Document).OrderByDescending(x => x.DocumentDate).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        private set { }
    }
```

This gives us the last movement operation asset encounters. So we can extract person and location info from it. It works, we use it both for listing and filtering (converted to `LINQ` with the help of `DelegateDecompiler` library). But it's slow and it will get slower as the database grow.

In the end, we go for a simpler but dirtier approach:

```
public class Asset
{
    public Person AssignedPerson { get; set; }
    public long? AssignedPersonId { get; set; }

    public Location AssignedLocation { get; set; }
    public long? AssignedLocationId { get; set; }
}
```

So yeah, we just bound `Asset` with it's currently assigned `Person` and `Location` directly (also keeping the old relations). These are updated when a new assignment happens.

But it feels like we're missing something here. Is it really clever to create extra first degree relations? Or is there a more efficient way to handle this kind of relation complexity?

*Btw, we disabled lazy loading globally so don't mind the missing `virtual` keywords.*

Comment: Is there an index on `DocumentDate`?

Comment: I'd have a hard time believing that Lazy Loading is disabled.  The reason is that either Movements should always be empty (unless you specify an include, but you didn't include the most crucial code, which is how are you retrieving an Asset, so this is all speculation) or you're always loading all Movements for all assets you retrieve (which is incredibly inefficient). You are also not caching the result of the select, so every time some piece of code accesses the property, the query runs again, very inefficient.

Comment: @GertArnold No there isn't. Will it help?

Comment: Yes, and other indexes, like `AssetMovement.DocumentId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you will potentially face with de-normalizing the assigned person and location into the Asset on top of the movement doc is that there is no way to enforce that the FK's referenced in the asset must correlate to the most recent movement, or even any movement associated to that asset.  You will need to rely on your system or a library from your system being the *only* code to touch these relationships, and that this code is bug-free. (No possibility of partially abandoned changes)

The computed/unmapped property to get the latest movement will get slow, as it will require you to eager-load your movements in order to access that property. That said, having a normalized many-to-many relationship in the data is not "slow", just how you propose to access it. A key performance improvement is to rely on projecting your operations down into DTOs, ViewModels, or anonymous types when you want to interact with the data rather than having your business logic attempt to interact with entity graphs directly. For example, if I want to get some details about an asset and its current location with your original model and I did this:

```
var asset = context.Assets
    .Include(x => Movements)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Document)
    .Single(x => x.AssetId == assetId);
```

This would allow me to access the LastMovementDoc property. To get here I had to load the complete asset, and all of it's movements. If I wanted to get a list of assets and filter on something like their current location, I have to load all of their movements.

With projection you can optimize the query to retrieve just the detail you care about. For instance to just get that asset and it's current movement doc.. (as entities)

```
var assetDetails = context.Assets
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Asset = x, 
        CurrentDocument = x.Movements
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Document.DocumentDate)
            .Select(m => m.Document)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).Single(x => x.Asset.AssetId == assetId);
```

This would generate an SQL statement that would just return the asset and it's latest document. This can be streamlined further by selecting a DTO or view model with just the fields from the asset and document you want. By following convention or providing a mapping configuration, Automapper can help hide this ugliness behind a `ProjectTo<T>` call, though I generally find that for stuff like this I prefer `Select` so it is easier to follow what is being retrieved. There is no need to eager load related data this way.

It involves a bit more code, but it is flexible and can result in far more efficient/performant querying of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We were already using DTOs with Automapper (comes with [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents)) but we always used the `Map<T>` method . Turns out, that method is calling for all the fields whether they're mapped or not. So changing them to `ProjectTo<T>` really made a difference! Now we're still testing so I'll update my question accordingly, including the query codes.

Comment: Yes, `ProjectTo` is designed to work with EF's `IQueryable` implementation and can speed things up considerably if the underlying query doesn't execute prematurely. By projecting your data to DTOs you don't need to worry about eager or lazy loading as the relevant tables will be included automatically. Profiling the database to capture SQL statements can help build a picture of what EF is trying to do behind the scenes to find bottlenecks.

Comment: Alright I'm just going to accept this. As implementing `ProjectTo` method is enough for our speed problem. Also that `Select(x => new {...})` query is great for retrieving complex queries like the count of an entities children together with its props. But that's a discussion for another topic. Thanks Steve!